# Why isn't the page.select() or page.$x(//select) function working for the SSENSE website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm working on a sneaker bot thats supposed to be all encompassing for any shoe site that I navigate to but it seems im stuck on [www.ssense.com](http://www.ssense.com)
because i have the select function laid out perfectly with both the standard page.select
() method and page.$x() select method and neither seem to be selecting the size that I want. For convenience I grabbed the snippet of the code from the rest that only needs to be used to select the size and there's a link preloaded as a test run to figuring this out but theoretically should work for any shoe link on the ssense.com website. if anyone could kindly point me in the right direction to figuring this out. I also want to mention that the code executes all the way up until the page.click("#pdpAddToBagButton"); command meaning the right levers are being pulled but theyre not doing anything and the add to bag button doesnt become clickable until a size has been selected.

essentially- select size executes, produces no results.

p.s. First time posting! Thanks for the help!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const readline = require("readline");
const RecaptchaPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');
const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36';

   //I grabbed this function from online to parse text in a regular format
   //when i developed this in its infancy, seems redundant
   //now i think but I'll keep it to save time since its already integrated


function getText(linkText) 
{
  linkText = linkText.replace(/\r\n|\r/g, "\n");
  linkText = linkText.replace(/\ +/g, " ");

  // Replace &nbsp; with a space 
  var nbspPattern = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g");
  return linkText.replace(nbspPattern, " ");
}




puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

var finishline = async function()
{
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();


//THIS IS THE SHOE LINK, replace with whatever shoe you want from the ssense website but it will essentially run the same so long as SIZE 41 is available
await page.goto('https://www.ssense.com/en-us/men/product/rick-owens/off-white-geobasket-high-top-sneakers/8371071',{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 });



var final = "";
const sizes = await page.$$('option')
var inner = "";


//searches for the correct size that im looking for which is size 41
for (var i=0; i < sizes.length; i++) 
{
  console.log("The For Loop is executing");
  let valueHandle = await sizes[i].getProperty('innerText');
  let linkText = await valueHandle.jsonValue();
  const text = getText(linkText);
  console.log(text);

  if (text.includes("41")) 
  {
    console.log("***************************Found********************************************");
    let sizeOp = await sizes[i].getProperty('value');
    let sizeOpText = await sizeOp.jsonValue();
    inner = text;
    console.log(sizeOpText);
    final = sizeOpText; 
    break;
    }
}

var thing = typeof final;

//uses xpath and inner value to select the size(prints the value and inner text as a result)
const [testgrab] = await page.$x('//*[@value="' + final + '"]');
console.log(await( await testgrab.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue());
console.log(await( await testgrab.getProperty('value')).jsonValue());

console.log("did the above print?")

await page.$x('//select[@id="pdpSizeDropdown"]//option[contains(@value , "' + final + '")]')

console.log(thing);
console.log(inner);

//this next sextion uses the standard page.select() method for trying to input the size based on the value of the option
await page.waitForSelector("#pdpSizeDropdown");
await page.waitFor(3000);

await page.select("#pdpSizeDropdown", final);
console.log()
console.log("was the size selected a second time?? if so the add to bag button SHOULD be clickable ")
await page.click("#pdpAddToBagButton");

console.log("if all goes well, this should print and a checkout button should appear")



}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you aware this site has both mobile version and desktop version form?
The number of option is twice (32) of all sizes options (16)
Do you prefer to automate the desktop version or mobile version of the site?
The selector `option` in

```
const sizes = await page.$$('option')
```

isn't quite match to select all the options for one version only.

Use `.pdp-desktop select#pdpSizeDropdown option` for desktop only,

```
const sizes = await page.$$('.pdp-desktop select#pdpSizeDropdown option')
```

and `.pdp-mobile select#pdpSizeDropdown option` for mobile only.

```
const sizes = await page.$$('.pdp-mobile select#pdpSizeDropdown option')
```